# Can't make jQuery to show Tabbed Navigation content

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm trying to make a tabbed navigation using buttoms instead of UL & LI

I've run into a problem on the Jquery code showing the section that corresponds to the clicked tab.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="tab-1">Copenhagen</button>
    <button class="tab-2">London</button>
    <button class="tab-3">New York</button>
</div>

<div id="content">

    <div class="tab-1">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(function(){
        $('.container button:first').addClass('active');
        $('#content div').hide();
        $('#content div:first').show();

        $('.container button').on('click',function(){
            $('.container button').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active')

            $('#content div').hide();
            var activeTab = $(this).attr('class');
            alert(activeTab);

            $(activeTab).show();
            return false;
        });
    })

});
```

The line above return doesn't show the div section that corresponds to the clicked tab.

I've used class as a navigation handle between the tabs and the section to show but I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it.

Please help or suggest a better way to handle the show section.

regards
Flemming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All content divs have the same class.

```js
$('.container button:first').addClass('active');
$('#content div').hide();
$('#content div:first').show();

$('.container button').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.container button').removeClass('active');
    var activeTab = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).addClass('active')
    $('#content div').hide();
    $('#content div.' + activeTab).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <button class="tab-1">Copenhagen</button>
    <button class="tab-2">London</button>
    <button class="tab-3">New York</button>
</div>

<div id="content">

    <div class="tab-1">
        <p>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-2">
       <p>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-3">
        <p>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm

The div class error must have been an editing error since I got the right code in my ide. 

But the change to my script really help me out here.

Thank you so much :o)